# SocialEngine Zend getting user profile picture

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am trying to get a users profile picture by using

```
$this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon');
```

or

```
$this->htmlLink($this->viewer()->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon'))
```

The this->viewer gets the person who is viewing the page and outputs their user_id and a link. I mimicked the output of that but it refuses to accept it. It errors out with 'Item must be a valid item." I have searched through the code and when users upload images it for some reason is hashed and put into hashed folders which i can't just pull from. But using the above functions do not work if i wanted to get the profile picture of someone else besides the current viewer or pageSubject. Does anyone know how to get this thing to work?

The lack of socialengine help and awful api are making this hard.

Comment: open the view script which is displaying the user profile picture. there you can track it down

Comment: Ive seen the view script and they are the same. My problem is that viewer() creates a  instance of an "item" which i cannot recreate no matter what i try. I have traced this viewer() function further and further and im getting lost further down the rabbit hole i go.

Comment: say if user A is logged in and he is viewing user B's profile. Now you want to get user A's profile picture or user B's profile picture?

Comment: No no, solutions go as answers please.

Comment: Not quite sure how you want the answer displayed. I see it was edited out of my original post so should it go under the answer that ive selected as correct? Or just leave it be? Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->viewer()` actually is the logged-in user's object. If your user is not logged in this code won't output anything.

**Edit:** It is the user object. You can use `Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()` or if you know the user_id/email of viewer, `Engine_Api::_()->user()->getUser($user_id)`

Comment: I understand about the viewer but the viewer() function itself passes other variables and creates an item from an abstract that i cannot seem to recreate.

Comment: It is the user object.
You can user `Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()`
or if you know the user_id/email, 
`Engine_Api::_()->user()->getUser($user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use: `$this->viewer()->getIdentity()`.

Comment: oh and user B would be: $this->subject()->getOwner()->getIdentity()

Answer (score 0):

This will print image with profile link.

```
<?php
$member2 = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getUser($user_id);
echo $this->htmlLink($member2->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($member2, 'thumb.icon'), array('class' => 'placement_members_icon'))

?>
```

replace `$user_id` in first line with desired user id.... that you can get easily from any table or user table