# SocialEngine Zend getting viewed user_id

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm  trying to get the user_id of the profile I'm currently viewing in Social Engine.
This is for the user_id for currently logged in:

```
echo Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer()->getIdentity(); //currently logged in user_id
```

What is the syntax for getting the id of the profile I'm currently viewing?
Thanks :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609482/socialengine-zend-getting-user-profile-picture?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the 'view-ee' (i.e. the subject) you can use the following;

It's always good practice to check we have a subject initially and then fetch the identity of that user.

```
if(Engine_Api::_()->core()->hasSubject()){
    $user_id = Engine_Api::_()->core()->getSubject()->getIdentity());
} else {
    echo 'no subject on this page';
}
```

I've covered this and many more topics on my blog specifically about socialengine. See below;

http://garbtech.co.uk/socialengine-creating-widgets-for-user-profiles-getting-the-subject-rather-than-the-viewer-information/

Answer (score 0):

In socialengine, they follow this scenario...

> Viewer - Who viewed means logged-in user
>
> Subject - Viewer/public viewing something(page/profile/...)

**Example** ::

I logged in as Viewer1, and viewing albums of Viewer2

Viewer - Viewer1

Subject - Album of Viewer2 (Here Viewer2 was the owner of the subject)